# Is the following series convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am given the following series to determine if it is convergent. My problem is, I use 2 tests and once I get that the set is convergent, and the other time divergent.

The series is 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(a^n-a^{n+1}\right)$$

The root test: 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(a^n-a^{n+1}\right)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(a-a^{{\frac{1}{n}}+1}\right)=0$$

So this is convergent

The ratio test: 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^{n+1}-a^{n+2}}{a^n-a^{n+1}}=a$$

This is divergent?

In both cases n goes to infinity

What is wrong with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you think $(a^n-a^{n+1})^{1/n}$ = a-a^{1+1/n}?

Comment: You have a serious mistake of manipulating limits in applying the root test. You can't insert the $1/n$ inside.

Comment: Do you know what a telescoping series is? There is a simple closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^m (a^n-a^{n+1})$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio test gives you $a$, so you could definitely conclude that the series converges if $|a|<1$. However, more generally notice that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n-a^{n+1} = (a-a^2)+(a^2-a^3)+(a^3-a^4)+\ldots $$ Now regroup quantities carefully and see if you can get some things to cancel.

Lastly, as a general rule $(x+y)^z \neq x^z+y^z$.